# Php/MySQL: Storing images captions on database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `products` table which contains information about products.
Each products can have unlimited pictures. These pictures are stored in a folder named after their product's id, and that's fine as it is, I don't need database to store file names.

But each of these pictures have text captions.
**My question is, what is the best solution for storing these captions data?**

Should I create a table called `products_captions`, with the fields
`product_id, image_name, caption_text`

Or should I create a `captions_array` field in the product table, containing a serialized array of strings, with the array key corresponding to the file name?

Is there any standard for this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your requirement you can create another table for storing the images name with their captions and product id so when you want to get the caption related to product you can get it by passing product id to the table.

Answer (score 1):

store your caption in another table and map the Image and caption 
for example

```
field       column
--------------------
id          int
Image       Blob
captionID   int 


field           column
----------------------
captionID       int
cation          varchar(50)
```